# StyleBundle, how to include all the *.js files in a folder along with the *.js files in the subfolders

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

this is my code, but i'm not sure if i'm putting the correct virtual directories..

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/App_Data").IncludeDirectory("~/App_Data", "*.js", true));
```

this is my folder structure.. each with *.js files and also more subfolders with more *.js files..  do I have to IncludeDirectory All of these folders to get it to work?

- App_Data

  - Controllers
  - Directives
  - Filters
  - Models
  - Services

No matter what i try.... when i look at the source code i don't see it adding anything.  I'm not sure if i'm missing a step or what..

Comment: Not sure about this, but maybe it's the name, which needs to be a virtual path. The name you give it is a folder that exists. You should try `new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/Scripts").IncludeDirectory("~/App_Data", "*.js", true)`.

Comment: Along with what Alexander said, make sure you are including this bundle somewhere in your layout or page.

Comment: @AlexanderDerck maybe this is where it's confusing but where is "~/bundles/Scripts" located?  i physically don't see this folder yet everything on this page uses that

Comment: @Gavin oh maybe that's what i'm missing okay let me try

Comment: @user1189352:  "~/bundles/Scripts" is a `virtual`path, so you won't physically be able to see it in your project.

Comment: @Gavin i included @Scripts.Render("~/App_Data") in my html and it worked.  tyvm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody visiting for a quick answer:
After creating your bundles for CSS/JS, you must include them in your _Layout.cshtml or specific View.